# basic bash console mac

Tags: bash, console

I am very inexperienced with the console, I have been exploring rails and somehow my command root in the console used to be:

```
Ross-MacBook-Pro:....$
```

inadvertently it has now been changed to:

```
unknown68a86d472174:....$
```

What is this and how do i revert?

Can you suggest any guides to help me learn the basic anatomy of the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash is the same as in Linux.
You will find lots of materials to this topic in the net, e.g., here:
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

The matter with your prompt is probably because the standard configuration changes the prompt if you have a net connection. But you can set your `PS1`variable as you wish.

Comment: I see, so is there a default PS1 setting that I can revert to?

Comment: The default uses the hostname. I guess, you 've connected your Mac to a network where it got a new hostname via DHCP. Thus, setting the name (via Sytem Preferences->Sharing) should do what you want.

Comment: Many thanks... it seems that my problem was as a result of a dodgy routing change that I made on the way here, and it happened to coincide with a username change throwing me off! But thanks for the help, I really need to get my head around the terminal.